# If = 1 then answer is day shift else answer is night shift

Tags: python

with this program the outcome should display employee name, number , shift (day or night based on the number imputed) and hourly pay rate.

I've tried a few different ways and can "almost" get the desired results. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
# This Employee class holds general data about employess and will
# end up as the superclass for this example.
class Employee:
    #__init__ method initialzes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, emp_name, emp_number):
        self.__emp_name = emp_name
        self.__emp_number = emp_number

    # The set_emp_name method gets the employee name.
    def set_emp_name(self, emp_name):
        self.__emp_name = emp_name

    # The set_emp_name method gets the employee number.
    def set_emp_number(self, emp_number):
        self.__emp_number = emp_number

    # The get_emp_name method returns the employee name.
    def get_emp_name(self):
        return self.__emp_name

    # The get_emp_number method returns the employee number.
    def get_emp_number(self):
        return self.__emp_number



# The ProductionWorker class holds the general data from superclass Employee
# as well as Employee shift time and pay rate making it a subclass
# of Employee.
class ProductionWorker(Employee):
    # __init__ method initializes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, emp_name, emp_number, shift, payrate):
        # Call the superclass
        Employee.__init__(self, emp_name, emp_number)
        self.__shift = shift
        self.__payrate = payrate

        # The set_shift method get employee shift.
    def set_shift(self, shift):
        self.__shift = shift

        # The set_payrate method gets employee hourly pay rate.
    def set_payrate(self, payrate):
        self.__payrate = payrate

        # The get_shift method returns the employee shift.
    def get_shift(self):
        if self.shift == 1:
           self.shift = 'Day shift'
        elif self.shift == 2:
            self.shift = 'Night shift'
        return self.__shift

        # The get_payrate method returns the employee hourly pay rate.
    def get_payrate(self):
        return self.__payrate

# This program will test the Employee superclass and ProductionWorker subclass 
# by returning and displaying the gathered information.

import sys

# Get the Employee info.
emp_name = input('Employee Name: ')
emp_number = input('Employee Number: ')
shift = float(input ('Shift Number 1 or 2: '))
payrate = input('Hourly Pay Rate: $')


# Determine True or False for mailing list.
#if shift == 1:
    #print('Day')
#else:
    #print ('Night')

# Create an instance of the ProductionWorker class.
my_productionworker = ProductionWorker(emp_name, emp_number, shift, payrate)

# Display the object's data.
print('Employee Information')
print('---------------------')
print('Employee Name:', my_productionworker.get_emp_name())
print('Employee Number:', my_productionworker.get_emp_number())
print('Shift:', my_productionworker.get_shift())
print('Hourly Pay Rate:$', my_productionworker.get_payrate())
```

Comment: oh I #out the part if shift == 1 etc this worked but not sure how to make result print after my print('Shift:'.... line.

Comment: What are the results now and what are you expecting?

Comment: This is *not* how you write Python code. If you've got a teacher who is telling you to write those getters and setters, leave the class straight away and find a better one.

Comment: General code style quip. Don't use the __ variables, it causes name mangling and generally stuff in python is "open", so it's better to either just use self.value or self._value, not self.__value. Another thing, instead of "get" and "set" use [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not disagreeing with you at all but perhaps you could make a small suggestion on how OP could improve his/her mindset when writing object orientated code in Python. Regardless, +1 for mentioning that wrong approach.

Comment: thanks for the replies David Zhou this is the result as it stands:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Larry\Documents\LD.Docs\Python Class\Chap 12 #1 Employee.ver2.py", line 84, in <module>
    print('Shift:', my_productionworker.get_shift())
  File "C:\Users\Larry\Documents\LD.Docs\Python Class\Chap 12 #1 Employee.ver2.py", line 48, in get_shift
    if self.shift == 1:
AttributeError: 'ProductionWorker' object has no attribute 'shift' what I'm hoping for is the display to show: Shift Day or Shift Night

Comment: Daniel and Greg unfortunately this is an online class I'm taking and the instructor just goes from the text with very little interaction. I have 2 more assignments to complete this class and am doing the best I can via thanks to this forum and little to no instructor support. But have to deliver a final product in the format she requires. Thanks for information though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method

```
def get_shift(self):
    if self.shift == 1:
       self.shift = 'Day shift'
    elif self.shift == 2:
        self.shift = 'Night shift'
    return self.__shift
```

you're mixing up `.shift` and `.__shift`  In the `if` and `elif`, it should be `.__shift` and in the assignments it should be just `shift` (a local variable, not a member variable) and then you should `return` that local variable (or maybe just return directly from inside the if and elif, depending on how you feel about multiple exit points).

Also, it's a good practice to include a final `else` in your `if / elif`, possibly something like this:

```
 else:
    shift = 'Cannot convert {} to a valid shift.'.format(self.__shift)
```

or

```
 else:
    raise Exception('Invalid shift value {}.'.format(self.__shift)
```

which will alert you to the fact that you fell through all the valid options, and give you a hint as to what value is causing the problem.

BTW, you should not be using double underscore variables in this way and, in general, should not try to write Java code in Python.  I'd get rid of the getters and setters and just read and write the member values directly.

Comment: The reason you have getters and setters in languages like Java is because you can make class variables private, which is safer. You can't make class variables private in Python, so there's no point to getters and setters.

Comment: I think you mean instance members -- class members would require their own class-level getters and setters.  And you're right, although it is possible to simulate private instance members in Python (which is what the OP is trying to do), it's just not "generally done".  When it is required, Python actually has a Property decorator to abstract all the getter / setter redundancy out of the class.